# best way of getting the dimension of a selection in photoshop

Tags: website-design

When converting **psd** to **(x)html**, there's this time that you want to get the height/width of a particular selection. For example, you have an item which is to be converted as `<div>` in coding. Then the `<div>` requires a fixed width/height. How would you get it from the **psd**?

My way is to crop the **psd**, then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to get image size window. Is there a better way than this? Cause sometimes, cropping takes time depending on the **psd** file.

I wanna hear it from the pro webmasters. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a default workspace setup, there is an **Info** tab in the upper right-hand panel with the **Navigator** and **Histogram** options.

The **Info** tab will display the dimensions of your selection if you are using the selection tool.

You'll probably want to change your **Units and Grids** settings in **Edit** > **Preferences** > **Units and Grids** to get the dimensions in pixels.